# What is causing Craft CP assets(JS/CSS) to appear in front-end pages?

Tags: craft3, control-panel, frontend

Perhaps in some way related to [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28878/updating-matrix-field-from-font-end-with-entry-setfieldvalue-pulls-in-cp-bun), I've got a couple of front-end pages on our website that pull in the following files, which seem to all be CP files. These two pages each utilize plugins I've written, each one a different plugin, so there must be something I'm doing in my plugins that calls this stuff in. Any hints?

```
selectize.css
craft.css
charts.css 
axios.min.js
d3.js
element-resize-detector.js
jquery.js
jquery.mobile-events.min.js
velocity.js
garnish.js
jquery-ui.min.js
jquery.payment.js
picturefill.js
selectize.js
jquery.fileupload.js
xregexp-all.js
fabric.js
Craft.min.js
```

**EDIT:** Here is the relevant asset-bundle:

```
class LivestreamAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * Initializes the bundle.
     */
    public function init()
    {
        // define the path that your publishable resources live
        $this->sourcePath = "@kr37/livestream/assetbundles/livestream/dist";

        // define the dependencies
        $this->depends = [
            CpAsset::class,
        ];

        // define the relative path to CSS/JS files that should be registered with the page
        // when this asset bundle is registered
        $this->js = [
            'js/Livestream.js',
        ];

        $this->css = [
            'css/Livestream.css',
        ];

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Comment: are your plugin assets depending on CpAsset? those files are included in page by CpAsset. - look for YourPluginAsset file in src/assets folder of your plugin and check $this->depend=[CpAsset::class]; also you are probably registering YourPluginAsset class in your front end template.

Comment: You nailed it. I was re-purposing an assetbundle created by pluginfactory.io, and didn't notice that in there. Removing that fixes the problem. If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it. (Also I edited my question to include the offending lines.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those CP files are included by [CpAsset](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/fdfda241b463b4df2d81ef20ed411ca65599e4e7/src/web/assets/cp/CpAsset.php#L52) asset bundle.

if your plugin asset bundle depends on CpAsset:

```
class YourPluginAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->sourcePath = __DIR__ . '/dist';
        $this->depends = [
         CpAsset::class,
        ]
     //....
    }
}
```

and if you register your plugin asset in frontend or backend template:

```
{% do view.registerAssetBundle("ns\\prefix\\YourPluginAsset") %}
```

or via controller:

```
 $this->view->registerAssetBundle(YourPluginAsset::class);
```

those file are added to that page automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful!